# Vertical centering menu offset

Tags: html, ios, css

I'm trying to centre an image using the following code:

```
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Example of what is happening here: http://benjaminbrooksguitar.ipage.com/bishoprdp/

The problem is I have a menu bar fixed to the bottom of the screen which leaves the image looking not completely centred. 
Also on iOS Safari it looks even less centred... (my guess is that because safari's menu bar disappears when scrolled, the browser is making the wrong calculation).

Is there a way to vertical centre the image with taking into account the menu bar, so that the image sits perfectly between the top of the browser and the menu bar?

And also is there a fix for iOS Safari's changing menu bar problem?

Here's a screenshot from Chrome and also a screenshot of iOS Safari (to clarify, it only looks this extreme on the iOS version of Safari): 
http://benjaminbrooksguitar.ipage.com/bishoprdp/Screenshot2.jpg

Many thanks

p.s. I've not a high enough reputation to add images thus the links...

Comment: Can't help you on Safari. But on Firefox it looks fine.

Comment: Thanks but can you see that the image is not directly in between the top of the browser and the menu bar?

Answer (score 0):

This is a screensho of how it looks on Linux Firefox v38 [image: Linux Firefox v38].

To me it seems ok.

And this is how it looks on Chromium. [image: on Chromium]

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I've added a screenshot/s to demonstrate what I mean.

Comment: "    in iOS Safari 5-7, position:fixed will move to center of window with focus event on child text input field." Look  [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=position)